# access search from XML file

Tags: python, xml, ms-access

my code make a search in XML file ( the function "findTerminal") for a specific attribute name and pass it to an other function ( called DBAccess) to find that attribut in access database .
the attribute name is not concatenated in the database, i had to do that to make the comparison.
buut nothing happend when i execute the code ?

```
import csv
import pyodbc
from xml.dom import minidom



# *************************************

def DBAccess (Term):
 MDB = 'c:/test/mydb.mdb'
 DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
 PWD = ''

 conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=%s;DBQ=%s;PWD=%s' % (DRV,MDB,PWD))
 curs = conn.cursor()


 print 'connexion opened'
 SQL = 'SELECT * FROM gdo_arc;' # insert your query here
 curs.execute(SQL)


 curs.execute("select nat_arc from gdo_segment")
 rows = curs.fetchall()
 for row in rows:
      T = 'T' + row.tronson + '_' + row.noued1 + '-' + row.noued2
      if T == Term :
         print (' Terminal found')

 curs.close()
 conn.close()





#*************************************

def findTerminal():

 xmldoc = minidom.parse('c:\\test\mydoc.xml')
 #printing the number of blocs in my xml file
 itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('ACLineSegment') 

 for item in itemlist:
     found = False
     for child in item.childNodes:
        if child.nodeName == 'Terminal':
            found = True
     if not found:
         Term = item.getAttribute('Name')
         DBAccess (Term)        

 #***********************************


findTerminal()
```

Comment: Your `findTerminal` function has an `if not found` condition which seems like it should really be `if found` (based on your problem description). Also, in your `DBAccess` function you have two consecutive  `curs.execute()` calls that run two different SELECT queries so the results of the first SELECT are never used.

Comment: after some changes i got this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test\pgm.txt", line 57, in <module>
    findTerminal()
  File "C:\test\pgm.txt", line 52, in findTerminal
    DBAccess (Term)
  File "C:\test\pgm.txt", line 14, in DBAccess
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=%s;DBQ=%s;PWD=%s' % (DRV,MDB,PWD))
Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC] Source de donn\xe9es introuvable et nom de pilote non sp\xe9cifi\xe9 (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')